# We have $Y=aX-bX+b$ with $b>a$, find $\rho_{xy}$

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

The entire question is in the title, in case of any notation difference then $\rho_{xy}$ is the correlation coefficient.

I am posting this because I am stuck and unable to solve it, here is my attempt:

First,  I thought if I could instantly deduce anything from the fact that $b>a$ but this did not end up in anything nor in any formulas where this would be a condition.
I started working step by step by trying to do some algebra on the correlation coefficient formula and that is $\rho_{xy}=\frac{\sigma_{xy}}{\sigma_x\times\sigma_y}$

We know that $\sigma_{xy}=E(XY)-E(X)\times E(Y)$ and that $\sigma_x=E(X^2)-E^2(X)$, thus the formula can be rewritten as:

$\frac{E(XY)-E(X)\times E(Y)}{(E(X^2)-E^2(X))\times (E(Y^2)-E^2(Y))}$

From here, I tried replying $Y$ by $aX-bX+b$, cleaning up the algebraic mess a little, and trying to see if there is anywhere I can use the fact that $b>a$ but it all seemed like it leads to nothing, I think I went the bad route but I have no idea how I can start all over again with a different approach. Any help, hints or guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean $Y=aX-bX+b$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I will correct it now, sorry.

Comment: The following theorem is useful: the correlation between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ has absolute value one if and only if they are scalars $m \neq 0$ and$ b \in \mathbf{R}$ such that $Y = mX + b.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Covariance properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations) are your friends for this problem.

I write $\sigma_{xy} = \text{Cov}(X, Y)$.

Now
$$\begin{align}
\sigma_{xy} &= \text{Cov}(X, Y) \\
&= \text{Cov}(X, aX - bX + b) \\
&= \text{Cov}(X, aX) - \text{Cov}(X, bX) + \text{Cov}(X, b) \\
&= a\text{Cov}(X, X) - b\text{Cov}(X, X) + 0 \\
&= (a-b)\text{Cov}(X, X) \\
&= (a-b)\sigma_x^2\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Next, obviously we'll keep $\sigma_x$ as is in the denominator of $\rho_{xy}$, and note
$$\sigma^2_y = \text{Var}(Y) = \text{Var}(aX - bX + b) =\text{Var}(aX-bX) = \text{Var}((a-b)X) = (a-b)^2\sigma^2_x$$
so taking square roots, we obtain
$$\sigma_y = \sqrt{(a-b)^2\sigma_x^2} = |a-b|\sigma_x\text{.}$$
Because $|a - b| = |b-a|$ and $b > a$, we have $|a - b| = |b-a| = b - a$.

Can you finish this off?

Comment: Thank you, I finished it off correctly.